# Take input in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, input

how can i take an int or float or any numeric input from user except String because **.readline()** only take String as an input .
for example i want to take numbers from user in this example:

> println"Enter your age"
>
> var age:int =readInt()

This gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main() {
  val num = readLine()!!
  println(num.toInt())
}
```

You can read the input as string and then convert it to the data type you want later

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    with(Scanner(System.`in`)) {
       val a = nextInt()
       println(a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get input from a user, try:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = readLine()
    println(input)
}
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Input Int in Kotlin
var input:Int=Integer.valueOf(readLine())

Comment: var a:Int=Integer.valueOf(readLine())